# What is the English translation for the Korean text written on the mini-bus?

Tags: translation, the-office

In Season 5 *The Office* (US version), [Episode 23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Scott_Paper_Company) - Broke, at the beginning we see a minivan and on the side is some Korean text:

[image]

Pam thinks it says

> Hallelujah Church of Scranton

But does anyone know what it really says? sorry I had to increase the brightness and shadow highlights in order for the text to be legible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broke_(The_Office)) (and [Entertainment Weekly](https://web.archive.org/web/20090427092215/http://www.ew.com/ew/article/0,,20274605,00.html?)) it says "**Hallelujah Church of Scranton**".

> ''We got the van at a used car lot,'' Pam told us. ''We think it says
>   'Alleluia Church of Scranton' in Korean.''' I'm going to leave it to
>   one of you Korean-reading Dunderheads to verify this, but given how
>   the rest of the episode played out, let's assume that's accurate.
>
> The sun was coming up, and Pam wondered if Michael by any chance
>   brought coffee along for their delivery voyage. ''Milk and sugar,'' he
>   said, and handed her a gigantic travel mug. She took one sip and made
>   a disgusted face. ''Is this just milk and sugar?'' I think the best
>   part of this whole exchange was Ryan's strangely intense stare.
>
> Ryan, Pam, and Michael were unloading boxes in a client's parking lot
>   — do most businesses get paper delivered so early in the morning? Can
>   they not accept deliveries during the day? Hmmm... — when a Korean
>   woman headed for the van. ''It's not for the church!'' Pam shouts.
>   ''It's a paper company now.'' Pam knows how ridiculous she sounds, but
>   in another stand-out episode for Jenna Fischer, she's also trying to
>   keep it together.

[Google Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ys1HM.png) seems to concur

**스크랜튼 의 ' 할렐루야 교회**

Comment: I'd feel more confident about this if a Korean speaker could verify but you're probably right

Comment: That seems reasonable, I was hoping for some hidden Easter egg or dumb meaning

Comment: I agree that Google Translate seems to confirm it. But I'm not sure how those other sources are relevant... They seem to be just based on the episode and what Pam says, which is information the OP already had.

Comment: https://korean.stackexchange.com/a/4878/1677

Answer (score 5):

It literally says "Scranton Hallelujah Church" on it. The "Scranton" and  "Hallelujah" are spelled phonetically in Korean characters and the "Church" is the Korean word we Americans would pronounce "Gyo Hey". Every set of characters in Korean is a different syllable, in a way, and the Korean language doesn't ever put 3 consonants together in a row, so the first 4 sets of characters on the van says "Su" "Ku" "Ran" "Ton". The remaining characters says "Hallelujah Gyo Hey"